# how to pass data to laravel route using ajax call?

Tags: ajax, laravel, facebook-like

i am making a facebook like kind of thing and i am using ajax for this in which in ajax data the id of the post or photo will pass and it will be of type post and in route will go to controller for updation but for just testing now in route it will return any message or the id

**the ajax part(javascript)**

```
  $.ajax({
    url:"vote",
    type:"post",
    dataType:"text",
    data:{id:x},
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-Token':  $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
      },  
    success:function(data){
        console.log(data+"sucees");
    }
```

**the php part(route part in web.php)**

```
Route::post('/vote',function(){
  if(Request::ajax()){
    return Request::id();
}else{
  Return "fail";
}
});
```

**the error i am getting in console log**

> POST http://localhost:8000/vote 500 (Internal Server Error)

**but whenever i am doing this**

```
    Route::post('/vote',function(){
  if(Request::ajax()){
    return Request::id();
}
```

it is correctly returing the data in json format
**console log**

> {"id":"17"}sucees

help me anyone.

Comment: 500 (Internal Server Error) is a common HTTP status code, please show the exact error message. It must be there in the console log.

Comment: can we do Request;;id() if we are passing the id as data?

Comment: the full error :::  jquery.js:5 POST http://localhost:8000/vote 500 (Internal Server Error)
send @ jquery.js:5
ajax @ jquery.js:5
votenow @ post:296
onclick @ post:127

Comment: I think it is a typo, in your route file after else you have written `Return` instead of `return', change that and if the problem not solved please test it using insomnia or postman. Then post output here

Comment: no the problem is still existing . and the problem is coming only when i am returning the id()

Comment: You can not use Request::id if you are passing id data.

Comment: then? we can surely do like this:function(Request $req){    if($req->ajax()){
      return $req->id;}  but can we do it with Request::id or id() if not why?

Comment: Request $req returns a collection where you can access the request attributes using dart operator. But Request::id() directly calls a function in the vendor file ( In this case such function doesn't exist). There are function like user(), toArray(), userAgent().. that can be called using Request::function_name().